# MAMP Pro freezing after MAC sleep mode

Tags: macos, mamp, freeze, osx-elcapitan

I am using MAMP pro on My MACBook pro with MacOSX 10.11.6 El Capitan.
Both the OS and the program are up to date.

It happens very often that, especially when the Mac goes in sleep mode (lift down the screen), MAMP freezes and must be shut down. Worse, if I restart it, the servers does not restart and the program does not respond, too. The only way to solve the situation is a reboot. 
Could you help me? If I can provide more information, don't hesitate to ask. Thank you

Comment: Any resolution on this? I'm having the same exact problem. Wondering if this should have been posted on https://superuser.com/ instead.

Comment: I also opened a ticket on MAMP bugtracker. No answer yet. 
I reinstalled everything with the latest OS (High Sierra) and, so far, I have not experienced the issue. The only difference, apart the OS, is that I formatted the SDD with the new filesystem and selected the "case sensitive filesystem" option.
@TysonNero I would suggest you to dump all the databases, uninstall everything and reinstall MAMP , after that import the databases. Maybe it could help.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I tweeted MAMP yesterday. No response yet.